# How to combine multiple named Columns as a Row and sum of it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need a query in SQL to combine several rows in the same table.

```
L_Life_Amount  M_LifeAmount    L_Health_Amount    M_Health_amount
100                 200             300                 400
200                 300             400                 600
300                 400             500                 700
```

and I need to bring the below result set

```
InsuranceType  L_Amount     M_Amount    L_amount-M_amount   
Life amount    600          900         -300
Health amount   1200        1700        -500

Total           1800        2600        -800
```

Here I need to `sum` the values of `L_life_Amount(L_Amount)` and `sum`of  `M_Life_amount(M_Amount)` and display it as Life amount

the same way I need to do `sum` for `L_Helath_Amount(L_Amount)` and `sum` of `M_Health_Amount(M_Amount)` and display it as Health Amount

Finally I make the diff betweeen `L_amount and M-amount`  and make a total of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Cross Apply` with `table valued constructor` to *unpivot* the data then do the math

Something like this

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT insurancetype, 
       l_amount=Sum(l_amount), 
       m_amount=Sum(m_amount), 
       [l_amount-m_amount]=Sum([l_amount-m_amount]) 
FROM   yourtable 
       CROSS apply (VALUES (l_life_amount,m_lifeamount,
                            l_life_amount - m_lifeamount,'Life amount'),
                           (l_health_amount,m_health_amount,
                            l_health_amount - m_health_amount,'Health amount')) cs(l_amount, m_amount, [L_amount-M_amount],insurancetype) 
GROUP  BY insurancetype 
)
select insurancetype,
       l_amount,
       m_amount,
       [l_amount-m_amount]
From CTE
UNION ALL
Select 'Total',
       sum(l_amount),
       sum(m_amount),
       sum([l_amount-m_amount])
From CTE
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77183/6)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW Life AS
SELECT 'Life amount' AS InsuranceType,
       sum(L_Life_Amount) AS L_Amount,
       sum(M_Life_Amount) AS M_Amount,
       sum(L_Life_Amount) - sum(M_Life_Amount) AS L_amount-M_Amount
FROM <tablename>

CREATE VIEW Health AS
SELECT 'Health amount' AS InsuranceType,
       sum(L_Health_Amount) AS L_Amount,
       sum(M_Health_Amount) AS M_Amount,
       sum(L_Health_Amount) - sum(M_Health_Amount) AS L_amount-M_Amount
FROM <tablename>

CREATE VIEW Total AS
SELECT 'Total' AS InsuranceType,
       sum(L_Amount),
       sum(M_Amount),
       sum(L_Amount-M_Amount),
FROM Life UNION Health

SELECT * FROM Life UNION Health UNION Total
```

(Not sure if syntax is correct...)

Answer (score 0):

we can get this solution with the help of `CTE` and union in `CTE`

```
declare @temp table

(
L_Life_Amount int,
M_LifeAmount    int,
L_Health_Amount int,
M_Health_amount int
);


insert into @temp values (100, 200, 300, 400)
insert into @temp values (200, 300, 400, 600)
insert into @temp values (300, 400, 500, 700)


;with cte as(
select 'Life amount' as InsuranceType , sum(L_Life_Amount) L_Amount ,SUM(M_LifeAmount) M_Amount,sum(L_Life_Amount)- SUM(M_LifeAmount) as [L_amount-M_amount]  from @temp
union
select 'Health amount' as InsuranceType , sum(L_Health_Amount) L_Amount ,SUM(M_Health_amount) M_Amount, sum(L_Health_Amount)-SUM(M_Health_amount)  from @temp) 

select * from cte
union
select 'Total' , sum(L_Amount), sum(M_Amount),sum([L_amount-M_amount]) from cte
```